# html5 cache, update every time user is online

Tags: javascript, php, html, caching

Html5 cache is a mechanism that store website in browser memory, so you can load it while being off-line. It reads cache-manifest file to recognize which urls should be cached, which not.

Once it cache your website, it will stuck forever, even if you are on-line! Always you will get cached version of website. Unless manifest file content gets changed.

The question is how to update html5 cache every time when user is online?

Comment: the user need to visit your url again for it to update

Comment: Yes, but also manifest needs to be updated too. And this is what I want to skip.

Comment: You should put in the manifest only files which will stay static, like your clientside templates (JS, or some static html) everything, what you not define there, will get requested from the server.. like you json data..

Comment: That is not the point in my case. My JS file changes often, html docs too. User should always be able to load offline last version of website, the last version when he was online. I'm even suprised that this isn't core possibility of html5 cache..

Comment: @ElSajko read my answer, you have to regenerate the manifest file each time you have a new version of the website

Comment: if things change often- then they should not be cached

Comment: Should be in some cases. Like for example server goes down, then users can load last updated offline version.

Answer (score 1):

Cache manifest, will get downloaded when you call:

```
 var appCache = window.applicationCache;

 appCache.update(); // Attempt to update the user's cache.

 ...

 if (appCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
      appCache.swapCache();  // The fetch was successful, swap in the new cache.
 }
```

But, the manifest file should be updated, if the file didn't changed, nothing will happen. So, you have to generate the manifest file. and add some comment with the lastUpdate Time or so..

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2010-06-18:v3

# Explicitly cached entries
index.html
css/style.css

# offline.html will be displayed if the user is offline
FALLBACK:
/ /offline.html

# All other resources (e.g. sites) require the user to be online. 
NETWORK:
*

# Additional resources to cache
CACHE:
images/logo1.png
images/logo2.png
images/logo3.png
```

Comment: As you can read in main post of question. I know that manifest needs to be updated. The question is, how to skip it.

Comment: You cannot skip it, you can use other techniques to cache data for example but if you use offline cache you have to deal with the specs

Comment: So the only way is run process in background that will be changing comment in manifest every lets say 1 minute.. This is odd. Why html5 cache is done that way? It's like "lets create cache for html5, but without main functionallity!"

Comment: You can use different techniques, I don't know what you can use on the server, but you could setup a file watcher, which will trigger regeneration of the manifest file when your html gets changed. or you could trigger the regeneration from the app, like /iamonline.php (which will do the dirty job and regenerate it)

Comment: File watcher is better I guess, it needs less server resources. But still.. Ugh. How they could f* up so simple thing. I cant use unofficial way, so I give up.